# Solve the Differential equation by separation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Solve the differential equation $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} =\frac{ty+t}{y}$ with starting value $y(2) = 0$

> I started with separation of variables and integrated afterwards:
>
> $$y\, dy=(ty+t)dt = \frac{y^2}{2} = \frac{(t^2)y+t^2}{2} + c$$

**After that I get stuck, can anyone help me out? Thanks**

Comment: You have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{y}{y + 1}~ dy = \int t ~ dt$. Can you proceed?

Comment: What did you do to get y/y+1?

Comment: You have $y~dy = t(y+1)~dt$. See it?

Comment: OMG, I feel so dumb after seeing it :( Thanks lol

Comment: Read the tag description before adding it.